# GCC is calling __fn_chk for gets and puts, how can I call the unsafe functions directly?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, debian, glibc

Despite calling `gets`, and `printf`, it seems GCC is instead dispatching to

```
call sym.imp.__gets_chk
call sym.imp.__printf_chk
```

I have another binary which was given to me -- I didn't compile it. It's also linked again `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` and it calls the functions directly. How can I link against these functions directly without linking against a `_chk` symbol?

**I've tried with and without `-fno-chkp-use-wrappers`.**

---

Current build options are

```
-m32 -fno-stack-protector -std=c89 -fno-PIE -no-pie -Os -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-chkp-use-wrappers
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help by the [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian) I found a solution, I added

```
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
```

To my options to GCC. Turns out this is only enabled when you use `-O`. In my case, I was using `-Os` and that enabled it!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I link against these functions directly without linking against a _chk symbol?

You can't: you must recompile this code without `-fstack-protector`.

> I explicitly have -fno-stack-protector

Well, *something* in your environment defines `__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 0`.

You can preprocess your source with:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -std=c89 -fno-chkp-use-wrappers -dD -E stack0.c
```

and verify that `__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL` is indeed defined, and figure out where that comes from.

Comment: I explicitly have `-fno-stack-protector` and I'm still getting these functions

Comment: It's not a Windows DLL call, it's me trying to compile https://github.com/hellosputnik/exploit-exercises/blob/master/Protostar/1%20Stack/Stack%200/stack0.c with the above options in the question on Ubuntu. What you're seeing with `sym.imp.__gets_chk` is just how radare2 disassembles it. The symbol is `__gets_chk` in the `imp` "flagspace".

Comment: I have `#define __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL 0` would that trigger this? how would I find out where it comes from? is this compiled in or from a real .h file?

Comment: I see it in `/usr/include/features.h` but it seems to be set to 0, that doesn't seem to be responsible?

Comment: When I run that command provided. `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -std=c89 -fno-chkp-use-wrappers -dD -E stack0.c` there is no mention of the chk functions at all? Is GCC doing this? or is the linker that GCC calls doing this?